# What ASP.NET MVC Conventions are out there?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I read on several places that ASP.NET MVC uses "conventions over configuration".
I specifically read [JohnnyCoder's post](http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2009/04/07/aspnet-mvc-where-convention-really-matters/) about this issue where he states about a specific convention (the view's name that is returned by a controller) that:

> Unless you are familiar with this convention and you adhere to it, the code can be a little confusing

He also discusses another convention - where views must be located if they are to be used by the controller.

So I was wondering - What other conventions should I be aware of?
How bad can it get if I won't adhere to a convention (either because I'm not aware of it or because I chose to) -can it crash my application or is the worse scenario my code being "confusing"?

I should that I'm a complete noob at ASP.NET MVC.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a convention, but strongly type your views and try to avoid using the ViewData collection.

Answer (score 1):

a controller class name **must always end with "Controller"** i.e. HomeController ...

that is one that will blow if you don't follow it.